# How would I make a table 'component' in angular, that works on different pages?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, coffeescript

What is the right way of creating a reusable table 'component' that will work with different JSON data from different controllers. On one page, with the specific controller, one table, on another page, with another controller, another table.

I've tried using a directive, which takes as parameter the controller of the page I am currently on, and stores it in a variable `obj`. Then in the template for the table, I did `{{ #{obj}.data.length }}` which worked perfectly, tho a little bit slow. I don't think this is the right way of doing it tho.

My ClientsController

```
angular
.module 'app.components.clients', ['app']
.controller 'ClientsController', ($http, $rootScope, $scope, clientsFactory) ->

  clientsFactory.fetch().then (response) => @data = response.data

  return @
```

Small piece of my router:

```
.when '/clients/active/',
      templateUrl: '/components/clients/clientsView.html'
      controller: 'ClientsController as clientsCtrl'
```

Basically I can display the data without problems on this page, but I need to display different data for different pages, the values of the table head will be different, for client I may have name and email, for user i can have birthday, email, first name, second name, last time active...

I want a table component that will receive data from the controller, and render the data into a table with filters, pagination...

Comment: Please specify whether both controllers getting similar attributes. I mean whether JSON structure is same or different?

Comment: The JSON structure is different.

Comment: In such case you should create individual component to render table view

Comment: Yes, I know this, the question tho is, how do i pass the data to the component?

Comment: Ok, I created sample component here check -https://plnkr.co/edit/869HvcH3VcLvgVslc6as?p=preview

Comment: @SumitDeshpande trying it right now

Comment: @SumitDeshpande This works as intended, but I've already tried it, its the same as passing the data from controller to controller, I don't know if this is the right way of doing it.

Comment: There is no need to pass data from controller to component you can create your own component. Can you post your sample code so that I can try for you

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/128741/discussion-between-sumit-deshpande-and-radu-dasclu).

Answer (score 0):

http://ui-grid.info/ <- helpful for angular tables.

Answer (score 0):

Based on your above description I created simple tableComponent as below -
Plunker reference as - https://plnkr.co/edit/EUS11z2PUuBqHFYpXUkP?p=preview

Component Code -

```
// Code goes here
var app = angular.module('myAPP', []);
app.component("tableComponent", {
  templateUrl: 'tableComponent.html',
  controllerAs: 'model',
  controller: ['utilityService', tableControllerFn]
});

function tableControllerFn(utilityService) {
  var model = this;
  model.listData = [];

  model.$onInit = function() {
    model.listData = utilityService.getTableData();
  }

  model.del = function(id) {
    var index = getSelectedIndex(id);
    if (index > -1) {
      model.listData.splice(index, 1);
    }
  };

  function getSelectedIndex(id) {
    for (var i = 0; i < model.listData.length; i++) {
      if (model.listData[i].id === id)
        return i;
    }
    return -1;
  }
}

app.service('utilityService', function() {
  this.getTableData = function() {
    return [{
      'id': 01,
      'nama': 'Faizah Pratiwi',
      'alamat': 'Malang'
    }, {
      'id': 02,
      'nama': 'Anastasya Putri',
      'alamat': 'Jember'
    }, {
      'id': 03,
      'nama': 'Sharon Natalia',
      'alamat': 'Tulungagung'
    }, {
      'id': 04,
      'nama': 'Faizah Pratiwi',
      'alamat': 'Malang'
    }]; //do intialization
  }
});
```

Component HTML -

```
<div>
  <table class="table">
    <tr>
      <th>ID</th>
      <th>Nama</th>
      <th>Alamat</th>
      <th>Action</th>
    </tr>
    <tr ng-repeat="x in model.listData">
      <td>{{x.id}}</td>
      <td>{{x.nama}}</td>
      <td>{{x.alamat}}</td>
      <td>
        <a href="#" ng-click="model.del(x.id)">Delete</a>
      </td>
    </tr>
  </table>
</div>
```

Usage:

```
<body ng-App="myAPP">
  <table-component></table-component>
</body>
```